# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop, but impossible to clear this issue [Solved]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, axios, jsx

Found myself in the unique position unable to overcome this error, having looked at all forum posts usually a mapping of some sort. Using the npm pkg react-ui-cards which takes a list of objects to render some stats in the card, requiring the properties name and value.

I used a useEffect hook to fetch this data and store in the array of objects using useState.

Then pass this array of objects to the npm pgk component.

Link To npm pkg with component properties:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ui-cards?activeTab=readme

I know that when mapping you need a key, so I added property key, but not sure where I can use it to clear this pesky warning. Here is the code snippet:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    UserCard
} from 'react-ui-cards';
import './InstallMain.css'
import {
    useEffect,
    useState
} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


function InstalllMain() {

    const [stat, setStats] = useState([{}])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const result = await axios(
                'https://api.github.com/users/nikhilsurfingaus',
            );
            const arr = result.data
            const test = [{
                    key: '1',
                    name: 'Followers',
                    value: arr.followers,
                },
                {
                    key: '2',
                    name: 'Following',
                    value: arr.following,
                },
                {
                    key: '3',
                    name: 'Repos',
                    value: arr.public_repos,
                },
            ]
            setStats(test)

        }
        fetchData();

    }, []);


    return ( <
        >
        <
        div className = "head" >
        <
        h1 > Install Program Guide < /h1> < /
        div > <
        div className = "prof" >
        <
        UserCard float header = 'https://i.imgur.com/vRAtM3i.jpg'
        avatar = 'https://i.imgur.com/XJxqvsU.jpg'
        name = 'Nikhil Naik'
        positionName = 'Github Profile'
        stats = {
            stat
        }
        key = {
            stat.map(a => a.key)
        }
        /> < /
        div > <
        />
    )
}

export default InstalllMain
```

Comment: Is this the component that React says you have an issue with?

Comment: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the top-level render call using <div>. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but shouldn't you map and render `UserCard` ? :

```
<div className="prof">
  {stat.map((a, i) => (
    <UserCard
      float
      header='https://i.imgur.com/vRAtM3i.jpg'
      avatar='https://i.imgur.com/XJxqvsU.jpg'
      name='Nikhil Naik'
      positionName='Github Profile'
      stats={a}
      key={i}
    />
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: UserCard is a component which takes just stats as an array of objects, no mapping done, i think mapping is already done by the npm pkg author

Comment: From documentation "Stats: an array of objects with attributes 'name' and 'value' - this is displayed in the card's footer"

Comment: when you `console.log` stat, what is the output ?

Comment: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{key: '1', name: 'Followers', value: 2}
1
: 
{key: '2', name: 'Following', value: 6}
2
: 
{key: '3', name: 'Repos', value: 20}
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)

Comment: So yes, you have to map yourself. Actually it is not possible for a package to map your own state. You have an array of object, so you have to map it and set the key with the index or a.key and you'll no longer have the error

Comment: If i mapped myself i would end up with three cards each with a single stats section. I need 1 card with a stats section containing 3 stats just like it was designed to do:

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ui-cards?activeTab=readme

Comment: You have 3 cards because you set your state with 3 objects. This package allows you to create card ui. It has nothing to do with mapping

Comment: I tried your code and got errors:
Uncaught TypeError: e.map is not a function
The above error occurred in the <O> component:
Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.


WARNING in [eslint] 
src\components\InstalllMain.jsx   
  Line 40:10:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'stat'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Can you try the code i updated ?

Comment: The code broke, same error: TypeError: e.map is not a function, react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <O> component:
At least the Key error is gone ahahahha

Comment: For context the error i got intially was : Check the top-level render call using <div>. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
Could this mean a key is needed elswherer like in the div or somthing or the parent

Comment: This is the parent:
function Intsall() {
  return (
    <>
      <InstalllMain />
    </>
  )
}
export default Intsall

Comment: I can't bring further help. e.map is not in the code i provided

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

Change:

```
    const [stat, setStats] = useState([{}])
```

To:

```
    const [stat, setStats] = useState([])
```

Not sure why the difference between an array and array of objects prompted this, but it cleared the error